# Push notification alerts based off of user set price

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I have been using background app refresh to handle my price alerts (if user set price becomes > the current price then alert user) but this is too slow and can go hours or days without alerting (not made for this I know). So I want to alert the user using push. I already have the UI for the alert settings. I am pulling the price data from a 3rd party's json.

How do I take the user inputed price value and constantly compare it with the current price to see if a push alert needs to be sent? I also would like to have a price badge that updates every 15 or so mins (right now that is also done wit background app refresh). Can I just push the price every 15 for the badge and compare with the user set value in the app delegate too.

I would think this is a common task but can't seem to find any resources for using push in this way, only to send manual updates. I have looked at services like Pusher, is that the right way to go?

Comment: You need to do the comparison on the server-side.